# Calculating nearest distance with nngeo

Tags: r, sf

I need to calculate the nearest distance between objects (schools). I have two sf-data-frames with lon/lat.

The way I understand the output of st_nn is, that dist gives me the minimum distance to the next neighbor, while nn gives me the index of this neighbor. Ideally I do want to have the ID of the nearest neighbor and not the index. I used this code:

```
data01 <- read.delim2('0708.txt',header = TRUE, sep = ";", dec = ".")

data01$sps[is.na(data01$sps)]<-0


special <- subset(data01, sps == 1,
                  select=c(id, geo, sps, lon, lat))
no_special <- subset(data01, sps == 0,
                     select=c(id, geo, sps, lon, lat))


sf_special <- st_as_sf(special,
                       coords = c("lon", "lat"), # x, y (order matters)
                       crs = 4326)

sf_no_special <- st_as_sf(no_special,
                          coords = c("lon", "lat"), # x, y (order matters)
                          crs = 4326)



nearest <- st_nn(sf_special,sf_no_special, k = 1, returnDist = T,  progress = FALSE)


special$dist = nn_dist$dist
special$n = nn_dist$nn
```

Now the Output looks like this:

```
      id                                          geo sps      lon      lat     dist  n
8  23880 Blankartstr. 13;53474;Bad Neuenahr-Ahrweiler   1 7.102950 50.54219 2088.908  6
32 14176          Siegener Str. 26;57610;Altenkirchen   1 7.651246 50.68972 918.4893 30
35 26147        Johannes-Krell-Str. 17;57518;Betzdorf   1 7.851260 50.79092 589.7386 52
45 13408                 Schulstr.;57580;Gebhardshain   1 7.823415 50.74588 3302.691 48
46 10435              Martin-Luther-Str. 4;57577;Hamm   1 7.669567 50.76203 2005.314 38
62 23954                   Schulstr. 10;67577;Alsheim   1 8.335559 49.76163 3584.156 68
```

A small sample of my data:

```
> dput(droplevels(data01[1:10, ]))
structure(list(typ = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = "Grundschule", class = "factor"), id = c(11725L, 
11739L, 26883L, 11863L, 11996L, 12060L, 22062L, 23880L, 12237L, 
12630L), str = structure(c(7L, 4L, 8L, 3L, 5L, 10L, 9L, 2L, 1L, 
6L), .Label = c("Ahrstr. 87", "Blankartstr. 13", "Eichenbacher Weg 26", 
"Kesslinger Str. 1", "Koblenzer Str.", "Quellenstr. 15", "Schulstr.", 
"Schulstr. 5", "Vehner Weg 31", "Weststr. 27"), class = "factor"), 
    plz = c(53518L, 53506L, 53505L, 53533L, 53498L, 53474L, 53474L, 
    53474L, 53505L, 56656L), ort = structure(c(1L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 
    5L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 7L, 8L), .Label = c("Adenau", "Ahrbrück", 
    "Altenahr", "Antweiler", "Bad Breisig", "Bad Neuenahr-Ahrweiler", 
    "Berg", "Brohl-Lützing"), class = "factor"), geo = structure(c(8L, 
    4L, 7L, 3L, 5L, 10L, 9L, 2L, 1L, 6L), .Label = c("Ahrstr. 87;53505;Berg", 
    "Blankartstr. 13;53474;Bad Neuenahr-Ahrweiler", "Eichenbacher Weg 26;53533;Antweiler", 
    "Kesslinger Str. 1;53506;Ahrbrück", "Koblenzer Str.;53498;Bad Breisig", 
    "Quellenstr. 15;56656;Brohl-Lützing", "Schulstr. 5;53505;Altenahr", 
    "Schulstr.;53518;Adenau", "Vehner Weg 31;53474;Bad Neuenahr-Ahrweiler", 
    "Weststr. 27;53474;Bad Neuenahr-Ahrweiler"), class = "factor"), 
    jahr = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L
    ), .Label = "2007/08", class = "factor"), name = structure(c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA), .Label = "GS Ahrweiler", class = "factor"), 
    start = structure(c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 1L, NA, NA
    ), .Label = "2001/02", class = "factor"), sps = c(0, 0, 0, 
    0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0), lon = c(6.9325459, 6.97516, 6.9875745, 
    6.825407, 7.3035599, 7.1322642, 7.1809, 7.10295, 6.93609, 
    7.32739), lat = c(50.382685, 50.48649, 50.5085722, 50.406783, 
    50.5055535, 50.5441126, 50.54013, 50.54219, 50.52239, 50.48599
    ), dist = list(2088.90766536052, 918.489268082922, 589.738579014495, 
        3302.69115170858, 2005.31411895232, 3584.15570982643, 
        366.260782140767, 2694.12065272956, 5257.32234958339, 
        1700.27776226661), n = list(6L, 30L, 52L, 48L, 38L, 68L, 
        58L, 84L, 142L, 138L)), row.names = c(NA, 10L), class = "data.frame")
> 


> dput(droplevels(special[1:10, ]))
structure(list(id = c(23880L, 14176L, 26147L, 13408L, 10435L, 
23954L, 20647L, 26447L, 15617L, 23173L), geo = structure(c(2L, 
9L, 4L, 8L, 5L, 6L, 3L, 10L, 1L, 7L), .Label = c("Beindestr.;55569;Monzingen", 
"Blankartstr. 13;53474;Bad Neuenahr-Ahrweiler", "Donnersbergstr. 32;55232;Alzey", 
"Johannes-Krell-Str. 17;57518;Betzdorf", "Martin-Luther-Str. 4;57577;Hamm", 
"Schulstr. 10;67577;Alsheim", "Schulstr.;55593;Rüdesheim", "Schulstr.;57580;Gebhardshain", 
"Siegener Str. 26;57610;Altenkirchen", "Weinstr. 79;67169;Kallstadt"
), class = "factor"), sps = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), 
    lon = c(7.10295, 7.6512462, 7.85126, 7.8234146, 7.6695674, 
    8.3355588, 8.1119607, 8.17405, 7.5906339, 7.8107492), lat = c(50.54219, 
    50.6897185, 50.79092, 50.7458834, 50.7620283, 49.7616261, 
    49.7408171, 49.49098, 49.7968555, 49.8468627), dist = list(
        2088.90766536052, 918.489268082922, 589.738579014495, 
        3302.69115170858, 2005.31411895232, 3584.15570982643, 
        366.260782140767, 2694.12065272956, 5257.32234958339, 
        1700.27776226661), n = list(6L, 30L, 52L, 48L, 38L, 68L, 
        58L, 84L, 142L, 138L)), row.names = c(8L, 32L, 35L, 45L, 
46L, 62L, 63L, 109L, 143L, 148L), class = "data.frame")

> dput(droplevels(no_special[1:10, ]))
structure(list(id = c(11725L, 11739L, 26883L, 11863L, 11996L, 
12060L, 22062L, 12237L, 12630L, 26537L), geo = structure(c(8L, 
4L, 7L, 2L, 5L, 10L, 9L, 1L, 6L, 3L), .Label = c("Ahrstr. 87;53505;Berg", 
"Eichenbacher Weg 26;53533;Antweiler", "Greimerstalweg 19;56659;Burgbrohl", 
"Kesslinger Str. 1;53506;Ahrbrück", "Koblenzer Str.;53498;Bad Breisig", 
"Quellenstr. 15;56656;Brohl-Lützing", "Schulstr. 5;53505;Altenahr", 
"Schulstr.;53518;Adenau", "Vehner Weg 31;53474;Bad Neuenahr-Ahrweiler", 
"Weststr. 27;53474;Bad Neuenahr-Ahrweiler"), class = "factor"), 
    sps = c(0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), lon = c(6.9325459, 
    6.97516, 6.9875745, 6.825407, 7.3035599, 7.1322642, 7.1809, 
    6.93609, 7.32739, 7.27089), lat = c(50.382685, 50.48649, 
    50.5085722, 50.406783, 50.5055535, 50.5441126, 50.54013, 
    50.52239, 50.48599, 50.45707)), row.names = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 
4L, 5L, 6L, 7L, 9L, 10L, 11L), class = "data.frame")
```

Any idea how I can use the index n of the next neighbor to get the corresponding ID (see Data; I use ID to identify the objects)